# What happens when bandwidth is exceeded with a Microsoft SQL Server connection?

Tags: sql-server, bandwidth

The application used by a group of 100+ users was made with VB6 and RDO. A replacement is coming, but the old one is still maintained. Users moved to a different building across the street and problems began. My opinion regarding the problem has been bandwidth, but I've had to argue with others who say it's database. Users regularly experience network slowness using the application, but also workstation tasks in general. The application moves large audio files and indexes them on occasion as well as others. Occasionally the database becomes hung. We have many top end, robust SQL Servers, so it is not a server problem. What I figured out is, a transaction is begun on a connection, but fails to complete properly because of a communication error. Updates from other connections become blocked, they continue stacking up, and users are down half a day. What I've begun doing the moment I'm told of a problem, after verifying the database is hung, is set the database to single user then back to multiuser to clear connections. They must all restart their applications. Today I found out there is a bandwidth limit at their new location which they regularly max out. I think in the old location there was a big pipe servicing many people, but now they are on a small pipe servicing a small number of people, which is also less tolerant of momentary high bandwidth demands.

What I want to know is exactly what happens to packets, both coming and going, when a bandwidth limit is reached. Also I want to know what happens in SQL Server communication. Do some packets get dropped? Do they start arriving more out of sequence? Do timing problems occur?

I plan to start controlling such things as file moves through the application. But I also want to know what configurations are usually present on network nodes regarding transient high demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question.  Networking is very key (especially in Availability Groups or any sort of mirroring set up) to good performance.  When transactions complete on the SQL server, they are then placed in the output buffer.  The app then needs to 'pick up' that data, clear it's output buffer and continue on.  I think (without knowing your configuration) that your apps aren't able to complete the round trip because the network pipe is inundated with requests, so the apps can't get what they need to successfully finish and close out.  This causes havoc as the network can't keep up with what the apps and SQL server are trying to do.  Then you have a 200 car pileup on a 1 lane highway.

Hindsight being what it is, there should have been extensive testing on the network capacity before everyone moved across the street.  Clearly, that didn't happen so you are kind of left to do what you can with what you have.  If the company can't get a stable networking connection, the situation may be out of your control.  If you're the DBA, I highly recommend you speak to your higher ups and explain to them the consequences of the reduced network capacity.  Often times, showing the consequences of inaction can lead to action.

Out of curiosity, is there any way you can analyze what waits are happening when the pileup happens?  I'm thinking it will be something along the lines of `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` which is usually indicative that SQL is waiting on the app to come back and pick up it's data.

Comment: You seem to understand my situation well. I'm applications, not data admin. I agree about testing in advance of the move. I have no way to look at the server console. They were looking in past and sending me screen snapshots. My main objective with my question here is validate my premise, that yes, a bandwidth issue such as they have can hose up the database and most likely will. I think packets are being dropped, and if not dropped then falling out of sequence to the extent they cannot be reassembled properly and once in awhile a transaction is left hanging.

Comment: They are going to raise the limit, but I don't think that's a cure, since moving files can eat up whatever bandwidth there is, and any new limit can be reached the same way. I'm working with technicians doing performance tests with some of the application functionality to establish a baseline, then when file moves are done. But I need to know that it is the bandwidth problem that hangs the database.

Comment: Without actually observing your system directly I can't say with absolute certainty.  From what you've told me, it seems that network saturation is the culprit.  A good indicator would be to check and see how much of your network is being used when this happens.